# Regex to get multiple items

Tags: java, regex

I understand the basic regex like finding things after a certain character but I want to be able to read `[(o, 21) (o, 17) (t, 3)]` each of those things, for instance 'o' means a certain task and '21' is the length.

I understand how to capture the inside just the brackets but not sure where to go from there, and I was thinking maybe id need 2 of these regex's for the task and then the length `\[(.*?)\]`

Expression:

```
/\[(.*?)\]/g
```

Text:

```
[(o, 21) (o, 17) (t, 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This would do the trick in the specific case:

```
(\([a-z]*, [0-9]*\)*)
```

This will include (...)
Or this without includeing:

```
([a-z]*, [0-9]*)
```